# How to change tintAdjustmentMode in SwiftUI macOS

Tags: macos, swiftui, toggle, tint

In my macOS SwiftUI app i have a toggle which looks fine, having a tint color

```
        Toggle(isOn: userManagedIsActive) {
            EmptyView()
        }
        .disabled(!canActivate)
        .toggleStyle(.switch)
        .overlay {
            if canActivate {
                Capsule(style: .continuous)
                    .stroke(toggleColor())
            }
        }
        .tint(toggleColor())
```

[image]
[image]

However when the window goes inactive, the switch color changes (on left i opened Finder)

[image]

- in iOS UIKit (even not macOS AppKit), this could have been controlled by `tintAdjustmentMode` but looks like there is no such option in SwiftUI

**how to make the toggle not change its tin, or option 2, how could i dimm the selector and overlay as well? to matched the .dimmed gray look?**

Answer (score -2):

```
struct CustomToggleStyle: ToggleStyle {
    var onColor: Color = .blue
        
    func makeBody(configuration: Configuration) -> some View {
        HStack {
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 12.5)
                .fill(configuration.isOn ? onColor : Color.gray)
                .overlay {
                   Circle()
                       .fill(.white)
                       .padding(3)
                       .offset(x: configuration.isOn ? 10 : -10)
                    }
                    .frame(width: 42, height: 25)
                    .onTapGesture {
                        withAnimation(.spring) {
                            configuration.isOn.toggle()
                        }
                    }
            }
        }
    }
```

Use above 'toggleStyle' like below

```
Toggle(isOn: userManagedIsActive) {
    EmptyView()
}
.toggleStyle(CustomToggleStyle(onColor: .purple))
```

Comment: this looks like doesn't answer the question, looks like a solution to coloring the toggle knob